# Converting MasterDetail Relationship to lookup and Its impacts on Reports

Tags: visualforce, reporting

We are working on urgent requiremnt where i am looking for the best approach to to achieve this.
What impact would be on report, i have read many articles that warns doing this as this might impact reports and dashboards. 
I was wondering will this changes really impacts reports and dashboards.

Any Suggestions are welcome

Comment: There are more thern 1000 reports and dashboards in production which sales rep uses

Comment: The key difference is that It will change the visibility of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a relationship from master detail to lookup can cause existing custom reports to become unusable due to the different standard report types available for each type of relationship. 
Its better to test your custom reports immediately after converting the relationship type. If you revert your relationship back to the original type, the reports are restored and become usable again.

**Master-Detail Standard Report Types**
Master object by itself ||
Master object with detail object ||
Master object with detail object and first lookup ||
Master object with detail object and second lookup

**Lookup Standard Report Types**
Object by itself ||
Object with first lookup ||
Object with second lookup ||
Object with third lookup ||

Refer to this article if you need more information : [Link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm&language=en_US)

Mark this as helpful if this is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks Pravan, so what you mean is just to change the record type to lookup and reports will work. It would be great if you explain some more ..thanks

Comment: Your Reports and Dashboards will be affected with your change. 
Because of the fact that, 
When you create a master detail relation ships, by default salesforce will create the below Report types :

Master object by itself || Master object with detail object || Master object with detail object and first lookup | 2nd lookup.
And your organisation might have created many custom reports based on the above report types. 
When you change the relationship to look up all the above report types that are created by default will be gone, which makes your custom reports unusable.